# How to update or overwrite in-scope variables?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have 2 funciton like so:

```
function test() {

    var item = {
        an_object:true
    };

    return function run_test() {
        console.log(item);
    };
}

function test2() {
    var script = test();
    var item = {
        different_object:true
    };

    script();
}
```

If i run test2(). I get this object:

```
{an_object:true};
```

but I want:

```
{different_object:true};
```

Is it possible to update internal variable **item** of **script** variable without resorting to using eval?

```
// I don't really want to use eval if i could help it. new Function() is also eval
eval('var func = '+script.toString());
func(); // output: {different_object:true}
```

Comment: No. It is **not** an *in-scope* variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `script` variable refers to a function that closes over `item`, but there's no way for you to use `script` to access `item` and adjust its properties, since it never exposes `item` (except to the console).

You couldn't even do it with `eval` or `new Function` working just from `script`, because you'd have to *replace* the function, which means it wouldn't close over `item` anymore.

---

As you mentioned, with `eval` it's possible to substitute an entirely new `item` variable and create a new function via `eval`:

```js
function test() {

    var item = {
        an_object:true
    };

    return function run_test() {
        console.log(item);
    };
}

function test2() {
    var script = test();
    console.log("Original:");
    script();
    var item = {
        different_object:true
    };
    script = eval("(" + script + ")");

    console.log("Updated:");
    script();
}

test2();
```

Or via `new Function`, by passing `item` in:

```js
function test() {

    var item = {
        an_object:true
    };

    return function run_test() {
        console.log(item);
    };
}

function test2() {
    var script = test();
    console.log("Original:");
    script();

    script = new Function("item",
      "return " + script
    )({
        different_object:true
    });

    console.log("Updated:");
    script();
}

test2();
```

...but those both require a round-trip through source code, and if the function `script` refers to had any *other* information it closed over and needed, it would stop working (it doesn't in this case).

Comment: It's not wanting to access the item, but rather overwrite the item, so instead script accessing the item from test(), it should use the item in test2() instead. Just asking if there is a way to do this. Eval would able to do it, but eval is slow compare to more direct means.

Comment: @Noobit: "Access" means "get" or "set". You can't access the item means you can't overwrite it, either. I mean, you could certainly just do `script = function() { console.log({different_object: true}); }` but I assume you don't want to. `eval` cannot do what I understand you to mean. Perhaps if you showed how you think it can, either I can explain why that doesn't work or gain a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Because variables in the previously defined function might changes out of scope, thus when the function run again, it would use the newer values rather than the old one.

For example i might not know what the var item is yet, but i can already build the function and add it to queue.

var queued = [];

queued.push(function(){ .... item .... }); // etc...

Then i would build item somewhere and execute stored function in a queue list by going through a loop, queue[i]();

Comment: @Noobit: Which function? What variables? The variables the function `script` refers to will remain for as long as `script` refers to that function, because the function closes over them (`item`, primarily, in this case). That's how closures work.

Comment: I understand that, but i'm asking is there any way to break the enclosure and overwrite the variable item reference stored in the script function?

Comment: @Noobit: Nope. :-) You'd have to take a round-trip through source as you suspected, which has some significant downsides. I've added to the answer above.